# Why doesn't work FirstpersonVrControls?

Tags: three.js

The code work pretty good in VR oculus, just firstperson moving doesn't work. How could I sold this problem?

```
controls = new THREE.VRControls( camera );
var fpVrControls = new THREE.FirstPersonVRControls(camera, scene);

fpVrControls.verticalMovement = true;
...



function animate(timestamp) {

    vrControls.update(); //when I paste this line scene doesn't work
    fpVrControls.update(timestamp); //when I paste this line scene doesn't work

    effect.requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vrControls.update();
```

`vrControls` is `undefined` at least in this scope. You use `controls` in this line: `controls = new THREE.VRControls( camera );`, not `vrControls`.

so unless you define `vrControls` elsewhere in your code, it will throw an error saying that `update() is not a function of undefined`.

Also, I can't see your HTML because you didn't include it, but THREE.VRcontrols is not in the core three.js or three.min.js, so you need to include it manually. It's in the threejs-master package under `\examples\js\controls`

EDIT

Always check the console. It's not defined because it's not loading.
[image]

Comment: thanks for the fast answer.
I replaced it, but the code doesn't work.
Should I use --
manager.render(scene, camera, timestamp); --
if yes, how can I set up it?

Comment: check edit. You can't use something that you don't load.

Comment: useful trick, I added Projector.js
and vrControls.update(); went good.
but fpVrControls.update(timestamp); still being wrong
https://jsfiddle.net/alaprajz/cqdyu4gf/1/

Comment: ok, they don't give error message anymore...but no any result,
new error:
unreachable code after return statement
What could I to do?

Comment: Decimal literals can start with a zero (0) followed by another decimal digit, but If all digits after the leading 0 are smaller than 8, the number is interpreted as an octal number. Because this is not the case with 08 and 09, JavaScript warns about it....How can I fix it?